# Stops encoding of '' to Quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi which require a string parameter.I send the Api Url and parameters to the views as viewbag from action so that I  can reuse the view for multiple WebApis

My controllerAction

```
  public ActionResult PreviousQuestions(String exam = "", int Number = 0)
            {          
                ViewBag.uri = "/api/pmp/GetNumberofQuestionByExam";
                ViewBag.param = "{ Number:  " + Number + ",Exam:\"First Term\"}";
                return View();
            }
```

My javascript inside view

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var uri ='@ViewBag.uri'; //Problem is here
        var param =  @ViewBag.param;
        $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: 'GET',
        data: param,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

        }
    });
```

Web Api

```
  public List<QuestionViewModel> GetPreviousQuestion(int Number, string Exam = "")
    {
    }
```

My problem is my Parameters get converted to

```
 var param =  { Number:  5,Exam:&quot;First Term&quot;};
```

which throws error.I know its silly and I am missing something or something like Creating json inside Action ..can someone suggest

```
JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
```

willnot work

Comment: Try doing `var param =  '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.param)'`

Comment: Can you give me the output of `console.log(param);` after `var param =  @ViewBag.param;`? Just add the code and tell the result.

Comment: @adiga can you add it as answer so that i can accept

Comment: @holydragon ..I got solution thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your js code to:

```
var param = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.param)
```

By default, Razor engine will encode everything. So, you need to use [`@Html.Raw()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) which returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those single quotes aren't needed.

Answer (score -3):

You have quotes inside quotes:

```
",Exam:\"First Term\"}"
```

Change your inside quotes like this:

```
",Exam:\'First Term\'}"
```

Comment: @Sreenath Ganga then remove the quotes alltogether

Comment: No xavier ajax cant recognise that format as string.any ways i got solution from @aldiga